# Combine two forms values in a single Submit but Radio Buttons not working properly- Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 html forms, form A and form B. I want to submit both form values when form B is submitted. The script is working fine. But it is passing all Radio button values (male, female, other) actually, only one selected radio button value should be passed to the next page.
The same is the case with checkboxes.

```
 <form name="A" id="formA">
    mydrink: <input type="text" value="beer" name="mydrink" /><br />

  <input type="radio" name="test" value="male" checked>
  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio"  name="test"  value="Female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
  <input type="radio"  name="test"  value="other">
  <label for="other">Other</label>

</form>

<br />
<form name="B" id="formB" action="forms.html" method="post">
bar: <input type="text" name="bar" value="doogans" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="Qnty" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>


$(function() {
    $( '#formB input[type = "submit"]' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
        $.each( $( '#formA' ).prop( 'elements' ), function( idx, elem ) {
            $( '#formB' ).append( $( '<input />' ).attr({
                type : "hidden",
                name : elem.name,
                value : elem.value
            }));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `element` is radio and if its checked or not i.e : `elem.type == "radio" && elem.checked == true` inside your each loop.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#formB input[type = "submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()//remove this just for testing
  $.each($('#formA').prop('elements'), function(idx, elem) {
    //check if elem.type is radio and its checked..
    if ((elem.type == "radio" && elem.checked == true) || (elem.type == "text")) {
      $('#formB').append($('<input />').attr({
        type: "text",
        name: elem.name,
        value: elem.value
      }));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="A" id="formA">
  mydrink: <input type="text" value="beer" name="mydrink" /><br />

  <input type="radio" name="test" value="male" checked>
  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="Female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="other">
  <label for="other">Other</label>

</form>

<br />
<form name="B" id="formB" action="forms.html" method="post">
  bar: <input type="text" name="bar" value="doogans" /><br />
  <input type="hidden" name="Qnty" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, if i want to add checkbox option also. Will it be like

   if ((elem.type == "radio" && elem.checked == true) || (elem.type == "checkbox" && elem.checked == true) || (elem.type == "text")) {

Comment: Yup . I think simply using `if (( elem.checked == true) || (elem.type == "text")) {` should also work . Try and see.

Answer (score 0):

In the `$.each`, you can specify two selectors, where the first will receive a `input[type="radio"]` with pseudo-class `:checked`, and the second selector will receive an `input[type="text"]`.

If necessary, you can specify more than two selectors to display in the **formB** form.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#formB input[type = "button"]').on("click", function (e) {
        $.each($('#formA input[type="radio"]:checked, #formA input[type="text"]'), function (idx, elem) {
            $("#formB").append(
                $("<input />").attr({
                    type: "hidden",
                    name: elem.name,
                    value: elem.value,
                })
            );
            console.log(elem.value);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="A" id="formA">
    mydrink: <input type="text" value="beer" name="mydrink" /><br />

    <input type="radio" name="test" value="male" checked />
    <label for="male">Male</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="Female" />
    <label for="female">Female</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="other" />
    <label for="other">Other</label>
</form>

<br />
<form name="B" id="formB" action="forms.html" method="post">
    bar: <input type="text" name="bar" value="doogans" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="Qnty" value="1" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" />
</form>
```